# Do I need to replace the killswitch before installing a new washer?

Tags: plumbing, washer

I bought a new washer from Home Depot and the guy refused to install it and claimed the Killswitch needs to be replaced before he installs the new washer.

He explained when he turned the switch upward, the water comes out. I do not know if this is a problem. The switch is always turned downward and in this position, the water does not leak out. This was never a problem for my old washer.

Do I need to pay someone to replace the switch? I was told it would cost me $250 including the parts.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. Pictures?

Comment: Can you add a picture of your valve (I assume that's what you mean by killswitch)? There are many different types of valves, and seeing yours might help us give you an answer.

Comment: Seems fishy, if it is water or electrical kill switch.  Either switch comes no where near 250, maybe 2.50.

Comment: Installers will find any excuse to not install the appliance you just bought. I think they charge a fat fee for showing up and pretending to try, and the additional pay for actually finishing the job isn't worth the additional time and effort. They make more by pretending to start five jobs in a day than by completing two or three.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri they make less money when they have to make a return visit because the customer isn't ready the first time.  And they would make even less money if they tried to fix the customer's long-standing plumbing issues.   And things would go south quickly if they did that without a license, or any training, in plumbing.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are talking about the water supply valve to the washing machine, and it sounds like it is failing to turn the water off when in the off position.   The free installation you get from Home Depot is performed by non-plumbers who are trained to turn that valve off in order to do the installation.  If it doesn't work they can't do their job.  They cannot and will not touch anything else in your plumbing system.  Their employer (HD) does not want the responsibility, especially not when they're not charging you.

It is possible to install the washer without fixing the valve; you can just turn off the entire water supply to your home.  (Unless your main valve is also broken!)  But you really should replace the washer valve.  It's important.  If something goes wrong with the washer, or with the hoses connecting it to the water supply, and if that valve doesn't work, you'll have to turn off all the water to your house until you can get it fixed.  Just do it now and be thankful they caught it.

You ought to be able to get HD to come back and finish the job later.

Comment: That's cute that you think the installers are HD employees. :) They're contractors working at a low hourly rate for the lowest of low-ball bidders for the HD installations. But, I get your point. +1

Comment: Yes agreed, I meant ultimate employer, not to imply any particular relationships.   HD pays the bill, they make the rules.

Answer (score 5):

To the uneducated or inexperienced installers, some residual water leaking from the old supply hoses is taken as a valve that is not closing.

I have had to "rescue" a few neighbors in my condo who had installers insist that the water valves were not shutting off the water.  After disconnecting the hoses from the washer and draining them in a bucket. I used a towel to wipe up any spilled water and the installers would finish the job.

Turn off the water (hot and cold). Turn on the washer to a wash cycle. This will relieve any pressure. If the valves are not closing, the water will run into the tub. No water running in the tub,turn off the washer and unplug. Loosen the hoses and use a big thick towel to catch any water.  Disconnect both hoses and tell the installers to do their job.